# Config Hermes to tibco ems ssl

Tags: ssl, jms, ssl-certificate, soapui, tibco-ems

To connect to tibco ems in ssl mode I am using below configuration

[image: Config]

However, I am receiving an exception "no trusted certificates are set" as below: 
[image]

Can anyone let me know is there any property that I am missing?
Or where should I place my .cer file?

My guess is that Hermes is not able to pick the .cer file. Hence throwing the above error.

Comment: What is value for `ssl_server_identity` on the server side configuration? Does both certificates match?

Comment: yes the certificate is valid one. As we use the same certificate in our java client to communicate with jms ssl.

And the ssl_server_identity is not at server side. So the client doesnot require it.

Comment: Server side meaning, it must have been specified in tibemsd.conf file. By the way, did you try the absolute path of certificate in hermes configuration file?

Comment: @Rao : Yes, I tried, placing certificate both ways(absolute and relative). I placed the cer file in .hermes folder and put the file name at SSLTrustedCertificate like: XXX.cer,

Also tried with giving absolute filename like C:\Fldr1\Fldr2\XXX.cer

And ssl_server_identity is not required in my case.